# Converting equation on the sphere to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Consider the following equation $-\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n} u = u$ where the $(\mathbb{S}^n,g)$ where $g$ is the usual metric induced by the inverse stereographic projection $S:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{S}^n$ such that
$$g = \frac{4}{(1+|x|^2)^2} g_{\mathbb{R}^n},$$
where
$$S(x) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+|x|^2},\frac{1-|x|^2}{1+|x|^2}\right).$$
Then consider $\phi(x) = u(S(x))$ where $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R.}$ I wonder what is the equation satisfied by the function $\phi?$

My attempt: If we set $s=S(x)$ then first $-\Delta_{g} u(s) = u(s).$ Then by the conformal relation of the spherical and flat metrics we observe that,
$$\Delta_g u = \frac{(1+|x|^2)^n}{2^{n}}\partial_j\left(\frac{2^n}{(1+|x|^2)^n}\frac{(1+|x|^2)^2}{4}\partial_j u\right)\\
=\frac{(1+|x|^2)^n}{4}\partial_j\left(\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{n-2}}\partial_j u\right)\\
=\frac{(1+|x|^2)^n}{4}\left(2(2-n)(1+|x|^2)^{1-n}x_j \partial_j u + (1+|x|^2)^{2-n}\partial_j^2 u\right)\\
=\frac{(2-n)(1+|x|^2)}{2}x_j \partial_j u+ \frac{(1+|x|^2)^{2}}{4}\partial_j^2 u.$$
Thus I am guessing that the answer should be
$$\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x)  = \frac{2(n-2)}{(1+|x|^2)}x\cdot \nabla \phi(x)-\frac{4}{(1+|x|^2)^2}\phi(x).$$
Is this the right expression and if so, then is there a way to get rid of the term $x\cdot \nabla \phi?$